# Roadmap for Windows Phone 8 App Development

Tags: windows-phone-8

Not sure if it's on-topic, but do we have something like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229583) for developing windows phone 8 apps? Or at least, do these skills translate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a centralized link where you can get "Roadmap" kind of details for [Windows Phone Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402535%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

And then this here is another important link [What's new in Windows Phone SDK 8.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206940%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Followed by:

[How to create your first app for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402526%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

[Next steps for Windows Phone 8 development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206937%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Finally you asked whether these(i guess Windows 8) skills translate .. Yes, ofcourse!!

[Cross Platform Development : Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 : C# + XAML](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitdey/archive/2012/11/06/cross-platform-development-windows-8-and-windows-phone-8-c-xaml.aspx)

Good luck :)

Comment: It's not as comprehensive as Windows Store apps. But it's definitely a start. Thanks for this.

Comment: another option is the "30 days to a Windows Phone 8 application" that's part of [Generation App](http://aka.ms/8in30)